# CN1 DAO keeps failing for no clear reason

Tags: sqlite, codenameone

I am trying to use CN1DataAccess to access SQLite database. Whenever I want to access any table, I get a null exception this is even though the database is there and the tables are there.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.codename1.io.Util.copyNoClose(Util.java:136)
at com.codename1.io.Util.copyNoClose(Util.java:122)
at com.codename1.io.Util.copy(Util.java:157)
at com.codename1.io.Util.copy(Util.java:111)
at com.codename1.io.Util.readInputStream(Util.java:206)
at com.codename1.io.Util.readToString(Util.java:194)
at com.codename1.io.Util.readToString(Util.java:182)
at ca.weblite.codename1.db.DAOProvider.loadDatabaseSQL(DAOProvider.java:100)
at ca.weblite.codename1.db.DAOProvider.getDatabaseSchema(DAOProvider.java:171)
at ca.weblite.codename1.db.DAOProvider.loadSchema(DAOProvider.java:248)
at ca.weblite.codename1.db.DAO.<init>(DAO.java:109)
at ca.weblite.codename1.db.DAOProvider$GenericDAO.<init>(DAOProvider.java:497)
at ca.weblite.codename1.db.DAOProvider.get(DAOProvider.java:474)
```

This is coming from this code segment

```
dbProvider = ServerAPI.dataProvider();
Log.p(dbProvider.toString());
categoryDAO = (DAO<Map>) dbProvider.get("CATEGORY");
```

The exception is thrown by the dbProvider.get("CATEGORY") statement. dbProvider is not null.

Just cannot trace where this is coming from. The database exists and the table CATEGORY exists. IF I use the codenameone db API directly, I am able to store and retrieve data.

Comment: It looks like the pre-processor to generate mappings didn't run. Were you able to use this in the past? Which IDE are you using? How did you map the preprocessor?

Comment: I am using Netbeans. Preprocessor? I did not see any reference to any preprocessor in the documentation https://github.com/shannah/cn1-data-access-lib.

Comment: You are right. the config.sql was not in the src directory. Fixed now. Thanks.